# How to change the name of downloading file in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have on server files with different characters istead of the names. 
It looks like **lkjhaklsjdhfklajs.txt**.
And I want to change the name of file.
In VueJS I do next:

```
<a
      :href="main.file"
      :download="main.user.name + ' - ' + main.title"
    >Скачать
    </a>
```

The document downloading, but the name not changing (there is the name of file that on the server). How to solve that problem?
P.S. Vue 2

Comment: Probably It's not same origin url so that's why It "doesn't work"

Comment: What web browser are you using? [Safari doesn't support setting the name of file downloads (until version 10.1).](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)